# Python3: Why is this syntax invalid?

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax-error

I am new to computer programing and am trying to modify an existing program. The original program is:

```
def main():
    print("hello, world!")
    x = int(input("give me a number! "))
    print(x+1,"is my favorite number!!")

main()
```

I have to modify it to say "hello, **name**" and say that x squared is the fav. number.

This is what I typed into vim:

```
def main()
    x = int(input("What is your name?")
    print("hello,"x)

main()

def main():
    y = int(input("give me a number!"))
    print(y**2, "is my favorite number!!")

main()
```

When I run python3 it responds with:

```
File "hello.py", line 1
    def main()
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What does this mean and how do I fix it?

Comment: Besides the actual errors, it's probably not a good idea to have two `main` functions.

Comment: @user2357112 Are you sure that at any given moment in his code, there are two main functions?

Comment: @Hyperboreus: I think you're completely missing the point. However the lifetime issues work out, defining two `main`s is a bad idea. The fact that only one is accessible at a time doesn't make it any better.

Comment: @user2357112 This, I do not understand. If the code was `a = 5; print (a); a = 7; print (a)`, nobody would say: "Hey, you have two a's. Don't do that." Python allows destructive (re-)assignment and functions are first class citizens. Why not treat them as such?

Comment: @Hyperboreus: Because `main` has an expected meaning, and defining two `main`s violates that expectation. `main` is supposed to be the code that runs when the module is executed as a script. There aren't supposed to be two identically-named `main`s doing different things.

Comment: Though it's laudable that you're using Vim, this has nothing to do with your syntax error. Please avoid tagging unrelated groups; I've removed the "vim" tag.

Answer (score 4):

You need a colon after your function definition on line one:

```
def main():
```

Answer (score 3):

You're missing a colon after `main()`

You're also missing a closing bracket here:

```
x = int(input("What is your name?")
```

I also think this, `print("hello,"x)` is supposed to be `print("hello", x)` (notice the comma)

Comment: Thank you! I have fixed that but now I have the problem:

    print("hello," x)
                   ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @KaraSilver: You have the comma inside the string, but you need the comma also for separating the `"hello, "` and the `x` -- as Aesthete wrote. You may want to display the comma. Then you should write `print("hello, ", x)`. Notice the second comma -- that one is important to fix the syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a colon after def main()

```
def main():
    x = int(input("What is your name?"))
    print("hello,"x)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use ":" after the function name in python and you missed one closing bracket !!

```
    def main() :
       x = int(input("What is your name?"))
       print("hello,"x)
```